# drupal ERPAL installation Requirements Views SavedSearches Clean URL not enabled

Tags: drupal, installation

Am new to drupal and i want to install drupal ERPAL i followed everything, and finally i installed successfully. After that while i run the file am getting following problem.

```
1.To start over, you must empty your existing database.
2.To install to a different database, edit the appropriate settings.php file in the sites folder.
3.To upgrade an existing installation, proceed to the [update script][1].
4.View your [existing site][2].
```

When i click existing site, it returns me to the same page
when i click update script, it shows requirement problem.

[image]

How do i enable the clear url, while installing drupal.

Thanks,
John Melchior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your server. Please check that you have mod_rewrite in your apache enabled.